# How to shift a textview in a new line if another textview is too long

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment

In a RelativeLayout  I have two TextViews aligned on the same row:
the first is aligned to the left, the second is aligned to the right.
How can I do to shift the second TextView in a "new row" only if the first texview is too long?

here's a screenshot of my application:

[image: this is a screenshot]

in the first case, the first textview "Something" and the second (the time) are aligned.
in the second case, i'd like to move the second textview under the first.

Here's the code of my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingRight="5dip"
android:paddingTop="5dip"
android:paddingBottom="5dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/immagine"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nickTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/immagine"
    android:text="Nickname"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messaggioTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nickTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/immagine"
    android:text="Messaggio"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="14dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oraText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nickTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nickTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:textSize="12dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/messaggioTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messaggioTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:textSize="12dip" />
```

the interested textviews are messaggioTextView and oraText.

Any idea?

Comment: where is the screenshot of your application ?

Comment: I can see the screenshot in the post. The link is [link](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/3466/chatscreenshot.jpg)

Comment: The solution for your problem is you need to set the fixed width for each textview....But not something you want(Shifting the textview)

Comment: if you count the no of texts means you can do this. just set the both textviews under a linear layout. the orientation is initially horizontal. if left side textview setting context increases .. change the orientation. to vertical.

Comment: @Release did you get the point check it will work for you

Comment: I'd like to have the same "layout" of whatsapp, that aligns the text of the user and the time if text is short, while creates a second row if the text of the user is too long

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messaggioTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dataText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nickTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/immagine"
    android:text="texttextkhgfkdklgfhkldfhghdgkljdlfkjhg;ldf;hhvasdv;svabsab"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="14dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messaggioTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:textSize="12dip" />
```

Comment: thank you @Janmejoy this is a solution of the problem, But i'd like to  expand the message from left to right entirely. In this case, i'd like to shift the time textview under the messagetextview

Comment: now i have this situation: [screenshot](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/22/immaginebt.png) but as you can see the message textview doesn't take all the space, because it stops before the oraText textview. I'd like to have this setting: if message textview is too long, then move the oraText Textview under

Comment: i try to be even more clear: if there is space: align the two textviews. else, move the second textview under the first (right align will not change)

Comment: @Release can you attach any screenshot,exactly what you need ...it will be easy to help you out..

Comment: ok... this is a [sample image](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/9650/immaginenpw.png) : when the textview of the message is short, message and timestamp are aligned. When the textview of the message is too long (it fills the whole line), timestamp goes on another line UNDER the message textview

Comment: mere code does not make a great answer, please provide explanation of code as well.

Comment: @KaranSharma it's self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a FlowLayout (or use one somebody else made [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)) for the text part of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

three way that I know,maybe better way exist:
1)load your text in Html and set it for text view (you can use html style and...)

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>text 1</font> <font color=#ffcc00>text 2</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

2)load your text in one text view but set spannable for each part of text.
3) create custom TextView class and compute length of text then if bigger than you want set another textview layout below this one